# p.jsx:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mnemonicToSeed')

Tags: reactjs

imtrying to get wallet id from this code but it only working in nodejs env but not in react error is why yhis error is coming when stating react app
dex.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mnemonicToSeed')
at getApplicationPrivateKey (App.jsx:7:28)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import StellarSdk from 'stellar-sdk';
import bip39 from 'bip39';
import { derivePath } from '@hawkingnetwork/ed25519-hd-key-rn';

const getApplicationPrivateKey = async (mnemonic) => {
  const seed = await bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic);
  const derivedSeed = derivePath("m/44'/314159'/0'", seed);

  return StellarSdk.Keypair.fromRawEd25519Seed(derivedSeed.key);
};

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const MNEMONIC = process.env.REACT_APP_MNEMONIC; // Get the mnemonic from environment variables
    getApplicationPrivateKey(MNEMONIC)
      .then((keypair) => {
        console.log(keypair.publicKey());
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Stellar Application Private Key</h1>
      <p>Check the console for the wallet ID.</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
``
```